# How to use no bar and full screen themes in Android?

Tags: android

I have a main screen and another two screen `A` and `B`. I would like the main screen be without an action bar while `A` and `B` do have them. So In my AndroidManifest.xml file I wrote:

```
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".A"
            android:label="A"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".B"
            android:label="B"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```

Now I want all of the screens be full. From previous topics I need to add:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen
```

But theme is already being occupied. How do I set to full screen and have no action bar in the main screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in the style file.

```
<style name="fullScreenTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/header_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_regular</item>
 </style>
```

use the below link either in application tag or activity tag.

```
 android:theme="@style/AppThemeActionBar"
```

Comment: Thanks, can you check my edit? i didn't quite understood your answer.

Comment: MainActivity is now on full screen

Comment: yes but my question is how to prevent same code? You have same code in both `MainScreen` and `AppTheme`

Comment: In AppTheme you are using parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" and in MainScreen you are using parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar".

So there is the different.

Answer (score 0):

To get `AppTheme`'s property inherited your `styles.xml` should look like this:

```
<!-- This is your "AppTheme" with ActionBar -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDarkColor</item>
</style>

<!-- This is your "FullScreen Style" with no duplicate property -->
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Then your `Manifest.xml` should look like this:

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".A"
            android:label="A"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".B"
            android:label="B"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
    </application>
```

Comment: you won't have full screen in the `mainActivity` though.

Comment: It will work because in your `Manifest.xml` file I used `<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">` for your `MainActivity`. Use it then see the result.